# Update deeply nested model upon save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, cocoon-gem

I'm attempting to update a deeply nested model from a model that is itself nested using cocoon.  (Don't worry, I'll clarify)

I have three Models: `Stock` `Stockholder` and `Folder`.  `Stock` `has_many :stockholders`, which are all nested via cocoon in a `form_for @stock`.  `Stockholder` `has_one :folder`.

Within my `stock` form, I have a table that lists out `stockholders` where I can add new ones (to reiterate, via cocoon).  To create a `Folder` for each new `Stockholder`, I have a `before_create` filter in my `Stockholder` model that creates a new `Folder` for each new `Stockholder` (see below)

```
before_create :build_default_folder

def build_default_folder
    logger.debug "Inside build_default_folder"
    build_folder(name: "#{self.holder_index}. #{self.holder_name}", company_id: self.warrant.company.id, parent_id: self.warrant.company.folders.find_by_name("#{self.warrant.security_series} #{self.warrant.security_class} Warrant").id)
    true
end
```

All of that works very well.

**The problem**

Is that I would like to add a method that updates the `Folder` attributes according to any changes in the stockholder information (say they change the name or something).  To this end, I've attempted to add the following.

```
before_save :update_default_folder

def update_default_folder
    logger.debug "Inside update_default_folder"
    self.folder.update_attributes(name: "#{self.holder_index}. #{self.holder_name}", company_id: self.warrant.company.id, parent_id: self.warrant.company.folders.find_by_name("#{self.warrant.security_series} #{self.warrant.security_class} Warrant").id)
    true
end
```

This however doesn't work and (particularly puzzling to me) is that `before_save` doesn't even seem to be firing.  My best guess would be that this is because `stockholder` is itself nested using cocoon (but I could be completely wrong about this).

Anyway, how might I achieve the desired functionality?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Where is this `before_update` defined? In `StockHolder`?

Comment: @nathanvda Ah, that could be my first issue, I was under the impression that it was an established callback (I must have misread the post I picked it up from).  However, I have also tried it with `before_save` to similar effect; I'll update my code above to avoid any further confusion.  My issue probably lies in selecting the proper callback for this situation.

Comment: Ha indeed! I missed that one myself :) What was not clear to me was in which model you defined the callback.

Comment: @nathanvda Oh, I see.  The callback is defined in `stockholder`.  I assumed that was kosher, given that `before_create` worked just fine.  Perhaps I'm mistaken?